# ZebPay - Direct sell from wallet

Tags: wallet, funds

I want to use ZebPay since I am from India but this question is applicable to all Bitcoin waletts like CoinBase. Can I sell directly from my wallet ?

For example if I have 1 BTC in my wallet can I sell it directly from there and get the funds in my bank account ?

Or do I have to wait for some third party to buy my bitcoins and then I can get paid ?

In short, can I sell to ZebPay or CoinBase directly for USD ?

Answer (score 2):

With Zebpay, you can sell directly and get your INR. You do not have to wait for a third party to buy your bitcoins like in a typical exchange.

I believe it is same with Coinbase to sell and get USD.

- Sandeep Goenka, co-founder, Zebpay.